# Get row from table in jsp

Tags: java, database, forms, jsp, servlets

I would like to handle specific row (user) in table. There are lot of users. I want to get user_id from table, click and display on another page. Now, I`m using post form. The problem is that Profile.jsp page display all the time the same user_id (first e.g. 2)?

jsp file:

```
//...
<table>
<tr>
<th>user_id</th>
<th>user_email</th>
<th>user_password</th>
<th>Show</th>
</tr> 
<%
  List<String> usersContainer = UsersWorker.GetUsers();

  Iterator<String> it = usersContainer.iterator();

  while (it.hasNext()) {

      out.print("<tr>");

      for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {

          if(i==0) {
          %><form action="ProfileServlet" method="post"><%

                  int user_id = Integer.parseInt(it.next());
                  %><td><input style="width: 30px" type="text" name="user_id" value="<% out.print(user_id); %>" readonly></td><%
          }
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(it.next());
          out.print("</td>");

          if(i==1) {

            %><td><input type="submit" value="Show"></td><%
          }
            %></form><%
      }
  out.print("</tr>");
 }
%>
</table>
```

Servlet java file:

```
//...
@WebServlet("/ProfileServlet")
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);

        String user_id = request.getParameter("user_id");
        System.out.print("user = " + user_id);
        request.setAttribute("user_id", user_id);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Index.jsp?subpage=6").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Profile jsp file:

```
<title>Profile</title>
<b>Profile</b>
<%
    String action = (String) request.getAttribute("user_id");
    %><br>user_id : <%=action %>
```

Comment: i guess problem is in Iterator<String> it = usersContainer.iterator(); check what's it.next() in debug.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you need to have unique input variable names. This means that you should have user_id0 for the first row, user_id1 for the second row and so on.

You should also add an additional submit button for every row (one submit button won't do)

```
<td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn"+i value="Submit"></td>
```

Note that buttons also should have unique names.

In your servlet, check which button has been clicked

```
private int getRecordIndex(HttpServletRequest request){

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        if(request.getParameter("submitBtn"+i)!=null)
            break;//button has been clicked

    }
    return i;
}
```

The value of i tells you which row has been selected so you can simply retrieve your value in doPost

```
 String user_id = request.getParameter("user_id"+getRecordIndex(request));
```

Comment: But <form action="ProfileServlet" method="post"> is separate for each row. Row name is each other bacause user_id is unique for all users.

Comment: Like I already said, you can't use a single user_id and make this work. Every input field has to have a unique name. So if you have 2 rows (like in your example), you really need 2 user_ids.